# SQL Agent Job - Error Creating Step

Tags: sql-server-agent, jobs

I get this error when trying to create a Job Step:

"*Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error..(Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS)*"

I do not get this error on other machines that have SQL Server.
I checked versions on each machine and all are the same...

*Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4033.0 (X64)   Jul  9 2014 16:04:25   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)*

I checked this link from Microsoft but does not seem to be a fix for SP2... https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/557402/ssms-can-no-longer-create-or-edit-job-steps

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it...

run this from cmd line/powershell...

regsvr32.exe "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sql server\100\dts\binn\dts.dll"

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/569732/creating-an-instance-of-the-com-component-with-clsid?tduid=(b1c7cdcb47d3ef96443cdf19a57073b3)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-lo_RDTVjauVtPImia9IDiQ)()